# react.js ReactComponent does not offer setState()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I seem to misunderstand some fundamental parts of React.js.

In http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

it says, that a react component has methods like setState().

But when I do this:

```
var MyComp = React.createClass({

   getInitialState: function() {
      return {dummy: "hello"};
   },

   render: function() { return React.DOM.h1(null, this.state.dummy + ", world!") }
}

var newComp = MyComp(null);

React.renderComponent(newComp, myDomElement);
MyComp.setState({dummy: "Good Bye"}); // Doesn't work. setState does not exist
newComp.setState({dummy: "Good Bye"}); // Doesn't work either. setState does not exist
```

There is no setState() method to be found. But in the docs it says Component API, so what am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Have a look at http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/03/21/react-v0.10.html#clone-on-mount. `newComp` is not really an instance of the component, it's a descriptor (`MyComp.setState` can't work at all of course because `MyComp` is basically the "class").

Comment: AHHH. So, the docs are wrong. not React.createClass creates an component instance, but React.renderComponent does. That makes sense.

Comment: The docs imply that calling `MyComp(null)` should return an instance, which it did at some point AFAIK. I will check if/how this should be updated.

Comment: ah, yes, you're right. Do you want to answer this question, so i can mark it?

Comment: It's really not a good idea to be calling functions within a component from outside that component - unless it's by some parental-child relationship that you're passing callbacks to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per this [blog post](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/03/21/react-v0.10.html#clone-on-mount) and [this writeup](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/8928067), calling `MyComp` doesn't return an instance anymore, it returns a lightweight descriptor.

Anti-pattern:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  customMethod: function() {
   return this.props.foo === 'bar';
  },
  render: function() {
  }
});

var component = <MyComponent foo="bar" />;
component.customMethod(); // invalid use!
```

Correct usage:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  customMethod: function() {
   return this.props.foo === 'bar';
  },
  render: function() {
  }
});

var realInstance = React.renderComponent(<MyComponent foo="bar" />, root);
realInstance.customMethod(); // this is valid
```